# Chrome for Android keeps bring up syncing/account screen at random

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-account

When I'm browsing Chrome on my Android phone, this screen keeps showing up even after I close it.

> [image]

I've tried updating Chrome and restarting my phone but it keeps showing.

How can I stop this screen from showing up randomly?